# Reusing reg model for panel data

Tags: regression, panel-data

When running panel regression, I have multiple equations with shared independent variables, control variables, and dependent variables, but different sets of interactive variables.

For the main model, I run OLS, FE, and RE to select one suitable model, then check the hypotheses, and finish choosing a suitable model. Is it appropriate to reuse the suitable (POLS/FE/RE) model from the main equation to others?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.